# Flash AS3 mouse move event listener and Timer Object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer, mouse

Ok I have this 100% width/height Flash embedded and when the user moves the mouse I want to display a panel, which disappears after x seconds if there is no more mouse movement.

I think I need an addEventListener, but I am not sure MOUSE_MOVE is the correct one.
When the mouse stops moving I need to start x seconds to hide the panel, so I think with a timer?

So fare I have this:

```
stop();

panel_mc.visible = false;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000, 1);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerHandler);

function showPanel(e:Event):void {
    panel_mc.visible = true;
    myTimer.start();
}
function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {
    panel_mc.visible = false;
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, showPanel);
```

It works, kinda, but when I move the mouse for more than 3 seconds I have a small Flash on the panel (hide - show)

Any corrections or better way would be appreciated, cheers

**EDIT** I got rid of the glitch by adding a reset before the start like this:

```
myTimer.reset();
myTimer.start();
```

Comment: You should answer your own question to close it, if you have already solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, mouse move will not help I think...

You should take your timer and check the mouse position every 3 seconds and if the position has not changed, show it.

Or try checking every 100 sec and always save the previous position and the last time it changed.

Comment: Please comment on down votes.  It is neither polite nor helpful for others to just click -1 without an explanation.

Comment: true, but I saw FFish answer which is much better and more elegant than mine - I guess was bit to fast there. Down vote was quit mean though